# How to send a dictionary with python http server/client

Tags: python, json, dictionary, server, client

I am using the libraries http.server and http.client in order to build a server/client structure. The server is always on and the client makes requests.

When the server is called, it calls a scraper that returns a dictionary and currently I send it like this:

`self.wfile.write(str(dictionary).encode("utf-8"))`

However the client receives a String that I have to parse. Is it possible that the server could send a dictionary? (Or even better, a json)

Comment: Binary, and then parse it as you need

Comment: `dictionary` is not a dictionary...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True that  I parse it as a string, I'll edit the post

Comment: @funnydman I would, but I've been told that this code may not be available in future python versions with the binary file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use `json.dumps({"a": 1, "b": 2})` and send your JSON object instead of encoding it as utf-8.

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick! 

Comment: Yes! I can accept the answer in 5 mins. It has a timeout, I'm kinda new to stackoverflow  Btw that would be in the self.wfile.write, right?

Comment: wfile.write(json.dumps(your_dictionary))